# In tensorflow, how to restore the certain variable_scope Variables into another certain variable_scope?

Tags: tensorflow

Now I have trained a model `A` and I need two model `A` instances because one of them just is fixed and untrainable for outputting and another is trainable for next network. **I design two variable_scope `A_train` and `A_untrain`**, I pre-trained `A` model in `variable_scope` `A_untrain` and restore the model also in this scope, code like:

```py
saver_untrain = tf.train.Saver(tf.get_collection(
                                   tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES,
                                   'A_untrain'))
saver_path = '~/models/model.ckpt'
# here pre-train model A
saver_untrain.save(sess, saver_path)
```

Now I need to restore the same model `A` parameters into the same model in scope `A_train`, but I cannot follow the previous code because the ckpt files restore the params like `A_untrain/input_w1` instread of `A_train/input_w1`. I want to know if there is a solution to my problem OR a better solution to make two instances which one is trainable and another is untrainable. Thanks a lot.

**EDIT_1**: I know I can realize my need use code like:

```py
saver_train = tf.train.Saver({'A_untrain/input_w1': A_train.input_w1})
```

but it will be unpractical when my variables amount is large, so I need to use the `variable_scope` to restore instead of the specific variables' names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution via numpy. We could save the trained parameters in the format of '*.npy' . When we need to load the parameters, we could `np.load` the npy file and then call `tf.assign()` in Session to assign the value.It works no matter what your variable_scope is.